# What is the equivalent to the genuine headlight bulb

Tags: headlight, kia, bulbs, sportage

My car is Kia Sportage 2018

I noticed that one of the headlights is not working

I managed to open that myself and tried to find in the supermarket the bulb that fits

after googling my car model I found that this is the genuine part

https://www.kia.parts/oem-parts/kia-bulb-1864428088l

I wonder what is the equivalent of this bulb from "Sylvania" bulbs?

Answer (score 2):

I found a bulb from Walmart "Sylvania 2357"

it cost me $7.31 CAD for 2

I called Kia dealer and they ask for $31.75 for 1 bulb.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question was already answered (by the one asking the question), it may actually be useful to consider using good quality bulbs rather than "el-cheapo" bulbs or "high-brightness" bulbs.

I recall a long time ago I had 2011 Toyota Yaris that still used halogen bulbs. The original bulbs as the car was sold were good, they lasted a long time and had acceptable brightness.

Then one day one of the bulbs failed. I went to a car parts shop selling 3rd party car parts and bought a "+X% brightness +Y% lifetime" bulb. For some strange reason, the bulb manufacturer was capable of conning me into believing that. Why this makes no sense is that if a bulb is brighter with the same wattage, it has to be hotter according to laws of physics, and a hotter filament has shorter lifetime not longer lifetime.

The "+X% brightness +Y% lifetime" bulb was bright as it claimed, but it lasted only a very short time. I suspect part of the reason for this was that this particular car had a high-ish charging voltage and also may have had beefy wires with less resistive drop than many other cars, so the high-brightness bulbs were very bright indeed. But in a car with high-ish charging voltage, all bulbs have short lifetime and high brightness. So for a car with high-ish charging voltage, you should use so-called "longlife" bulbs.

After using many of the "+X% brightness +Y% lifetime" bulbs, I gave up on they burning so fast and decided to find a long-life bulb. I didn't want to buy one from the dealership (would have been very expensive), so I only found one long-life bulbs from a store selling very very cheap car parts (that are generally regarded very low quality where I live). I installed it. It had a strange beam pattern and I think the reason for this was that its filament was slightly misaligned during manufacturing, because for the previous bulb that was in the same headlight, no such problem occurred. Also, the long-life bulb from this cheap car parts store had perhaps a little bit too low brighness.

Long story short, the original bulbs when the car was sold were the only that I considered to have acceptable brightness and acceptable lifetime (plus they didn't have beam pattern misalignment). By buying only these bulbs, I could have avoided a lot of annoyance.

I sold the car before reinstalling official bulbs on both left and right headlights. That was for long on my TODO list, using only official bulbs by the original manufacturer.